# Fuse two BERT encoded sentences in a single representation to be used as a neural network input

Tags: deep-learning, bert-language-model

I have two independent BERTs that encode two sentences. How can I fuse/combine the token-level representations to a single vector representation to be used as input to a fully connected network?

The naive solution would be to use the encoded [CLS] tokens of the two sentences. What would a more sophisticated solution involve? Would adding a self attention layer or even a full transformer encoder block help?

Comment: Framework? PyTorch or TensorFlow?

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat Tensorflow, but the question is framework-agnostic.

Comment: I asked cause I knew of a good notebook in which the author uses the token representations in different manners. Although it is not spot on but you might get an idea until someone answers. [here](https://www.kaggle.com/rhtsingh/utilizing-transformer-representations-efficiently) is the notebook but it's in PyTorch.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you can do with [SentenceTransformers](https://www.sbert.net/).
[image]